# Unable to access tomcat server on 8080 port from Google Compute Engine VM (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, google-compute-engine, firewall

I have created Virtual Machine Under Google Compute Engine and selected Windows Server 2012 R2 as OS for the server. I have installed Tomcat 8 and and it is running on 8080 HTTP port. I can access locally tomcat on browser using internal IP and localhost. But I can not able to access tomcat using external IP from my local computer.
Please help me if possible. My tomcat server configuration file of tomcat is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common issues for this:

1. You need to open port 8080 on [GCE's firewall](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls) in order for it to be accessible from outside GCE.
2. It is possible that Tomcat is only listening on the localhost. You might need to set the [HTTP Connector address attribute](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation) to 0.0.0.0 so that Tomcat listens on all addresses.

Comment: Hi David thank you for you suggestion. Suggestion worked. I have configured Google Compute Engine firewall as well as Windows Server 2012 R2 firewall for tomcat port. After that I can access tomcat using external ip from my local computer.

Comment: If you felt my comment fully answers your question, you can [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark the question as answered and give us both a bit of reputation bump