# Can't access the External IP on GCP

Tags: web-services, networking, google-cloud-platform, port

I've deployed my java application on VM instance. I'm able to access it with EXTERNALIP:8080 and i can access it with my domain "www.domain.com:8080". I've configured to tomcat server to port 80 so that i can access with EXTERNALIP. But my site is refusing to connet to that server. And the tcp:80 port is set to ingres 0.0.0.0/0 it is pointing to internal ip. i'm not finding a solution to point it to the external ip.
When i try to run with my external ip i'm getting message like..

```
This site can’t be reached
EXTERNALIP refused to connect.
```

Answer (score 0):

May you check this link [1], the answer may be helpful for this case.

[1] [Unable to access tomcat server on 8080 port from Google Compute Engine VM (Windows Server 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916674/unable-to-access-tomcat-server-on-8080-port-from-google-compute-engine-vm-windo)